# SOQL - How to query Lead email using Task object?

Tags: soql, leads, tasks

SOQL only. I can accessed the Name of the Lead from the Task object, however when I accessed the Lead email, even though the Lead record has an existing email, the email wasn't showing up.

This query will work. The name of the Lead will show up:

```
SELECT WhoId, Who.Name FROM Task
```

Doesn't work properly. Lead record has email but it's not showing:

```
SELECT WhoId, Who.Name, Who.Email FROM Task
```

Comment: Unfortunately, email is still not showing up even after referencing the object type to use.. (SELECT Id, Who.Id, Who.Type, Who.Email FROM Task WHERE Who.Type='Lead')

Comment: Nothing is showing up here either.. (
SELECT 
  TYPEOF Who 
     WHEN Lead THEN Name, Email 
     WHEN Contact Then Name, Email 
  END 
FROM Task
)

Comment: i need to query and get the result using the query editor only.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you tried [`TYPEOF`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

So

```
SELECT TYPEOF Who WHEN Lead THEN Name, Email WHEN Contact Then Name, Email END FROM Task where id = '00Txxx'
```

**With workbench**

- will return Lead.Email when Task.WhoId is a Lead

[image]

**With Developer Console**

- will return one row when Task.WhoId is a Lead
- but will not display any columns as Developer Console doesn't know how to display polymorphic queries